# How to make an Ajax request in Joomla Component

Tags: ajax, joomla

This a screen shot of what I get when I call my ajax request:

[image]

How do I run only the task, without printing the whole page? This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "index.php?option=com_similar&task=abc",
    data: {
        id: id,
        name: name,
        similar_id: similar_id,
    },
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#flash").fadeOut("slow");
$("#content"+similar_id).html(html);
} 
});
});

$(".close").click(function()
{
$("#votebox").slideUp("slow");
});

});
```

Comment: What do you mean with "without printing whole page"? To don't print anything? Also, you do not show your complete ajax request, it should end with }); .

Comment: look at the screenshot. i didnt wrote full ajax, because i dont think this is important here

Comment: I don't see what the expected output is? Should anyting happen at all?

Comment: for example i want to do simple echo. the results is that i get whole page with echo, instead of just echo

Comment: after echo statement just write exit.or paste the code of task in your post so it'll be easy to understand.

Comment: yep! it worked with exit. but will controller work well with exit();?

Comment: yes,if you are not accessing it somewhere else.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Don't go with exit or die**, Joomla! has it's nice way of dealing with this stuff.

The answers below are tested in Joomla! 2.5 & 3 (for 1.5. may work as well).

---

**General**

Your **URL** for the task needs to look like this:

`index.php?option=com_similar&task=abc&format=raw`

You than create the controller which will use the view, let's say Abc, which will contain the file view.raw.html (identical to a normal view file).

Below you have the code for generate a raw HTML response:

**/controller.php**

```
public function abc() 
{
    // Set view
    JRequest::setVar('view', 'Abc');
    parent::display();
}
```

**/views/abc/view.raw.php**

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

class SimilarViewAbc extends JView
{
    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

**/views/abc/tmpl/default.php**

```
<?php

echo "Hello World from /views/abc/tmpl/default.php";
```

*Note: This is the solution I would use if I had to return HTML (it's cleaner and follows Joomla logic). For returning simple JSON data, see below how to put everything in the controller.*

---

If you make your Ajax request to a **subcontroller**, like:

`index.php?option=com_similar&controller=abc&format=raw`

Than your subcontroller name (for the raw view) needs to be `abc.raw.php`.

This means also that you will / may have 2 subcontrollers named Abc.

If you return JSON, it may make sense to use `format=json` and `abc.json.php`. In Joomla 2.5. I had some issues getting this option to work (somehow the output was corrupted), so I used raw.

---

If you need to **generate a valid JSON response**, check out the docs page [Generating JSON output](http://docs.joomla.org/Generating_JSON_output)

```
// We assume that the whatver you do was a success.
$response = array("success" => true);
// You can also return something like:
$response = array("success" => false, "error"=> "Could not find ...");

// Get the document object.
$document = JFactory::getDocument();

// Set the MIME type for JSON output.
$document->setMimeEncoding('application/json');

// Change the suggested filename.
JResponse::setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename="result.json"');

echo json_encode($response);
```

You would generally put this code in the controller (you will call a model which will return the data you encode - a very common scenario). If you need to take it further, you can also create a JSON view (view.json.php), similar with the raw example.

---

**Security**

Now that the Ajax request is working, don't close the page yet. Read below.

Don't forget to check for request forgeries. `JSession::checkToken()` come in handy here. Read the documentation on How to add [CSRF anti-spoofing to forms](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms)

---

**Multilingual sites**

It may happen that if you don't send the language name in the request, Joomla won't translate the language strings you want.

Consider appending somehow the lang param to your request (like `&lang=de`).

---

*New in Joomla 3.2!* - [Joomla! Ajax Interface](https://github.com/Joomla-Ajax-Interface/component/blob/master/README.md)

Joomla now provides a lightweight way to handle Ajax request in a plugin or module. You may want to use the Joomla! Ajax Interface if you don't have already a component or if you need to make requests from a module your already have.

Comment: Great post! Something to be aware of sometimes Joomla has trouble with the display raw for ajax... http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1915019.  I have had to echo output from my controller for my ajax calls instead of passing it to the view for this very reason.

Comment: @Cleanshooter - I've added some information on dealing with subcontrollers. I use ajax quite a lot in my components and so far I haven't had any problems dealing with this stuff. If you have any problems feel free to post some code here what does not work so that we can gather more quality info on how Joomla! works. Thanks.

Comment: @ValentinDespa - There's a typo in your view.raw.php code. parrent::display($tpl) should be parent::display($tpl).

Comment: @mozami - Fixed, thank you. Feel free to edit any errors you find.

Comment: @ValentinDespa Tried to edit it but SO would not accept a 1 char edit :)
Thanks for the easy to follow solution!

Comment: Adding a note that JView now should be JViewLegacy, otherwise this answer still works.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to include the response output in some HTML element, append format=raw to your URL as mentioned above. Then you could have a controller function like this:

```
function abc(){

//... handle the request, read variables, whatever
print "this is what I want to place in my html";

}
```

The AJAX response will output everything you printed / echoed in the controller.