# Joomla 3.0 ajax call

Tags: ajax, joomla

Code for ajax call in joomla 3.0 i am using following method to call

```
function myAjaxCall1(surl, method, response_divid) {

  var req = new Request({
    method : 'POST',
    url : surl,
    data : method,
    onRequest : function() {
        document.getElementById(response_divid).innerHTML = '<span id="loading_img"></span>';
        return false;
    },
    onComplete : function(response) {
        document.getElementById(response_divid).innerHTML += response;
    }
  }).send();

}
```

but it is giving back HTML tags out put on respone, even i used in url tmpl=component

Comment: Are there any HTML tags inside `response_divid` to start off with?

Comment: What is the URL and data components of your request?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478108/how-to-make-an-ajax-request-in-joomla-component/13479338#13479338