# Access Joomla from external php-script

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

I wrote a component for Joomla 2.5 which uses jquery in the admin part. The js-script calles a helper php file (addrow.php), which returnes a new row for a table using Joomla's form fields. Because that file is outside of the Joomla framework I used these lines to make it work:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../..' )); 

require_once( JPATH_BASE.'includes/defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE.'includes/framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE.'libraries/joomla/factory.php' );
```

After the upgrade to Joomla 3.2, this didn't work anymore, I just got

> Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error

but by adding

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
```

it works again.

My question is, if this is in general the proper way to write external php-scripts for jquery?
And is getApplication('site') correct even if it's for admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No — read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478108/how-to-make-an-ajax-request-in-joomla-component) and this on "[Using Joomla Ajax Interface](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface)"
2. Yes, it's an acceptable form (although `JFactory::getApplication()` will default to the current entry point i.e. `site` or `administrator`.